# Travis Build Can't Find Diff::LCS::SpecHelper for Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to set up a Travis build for my Ruby project.  The tests are using rspec.  They pass locally using the default 'rake' task, but fail on the Travis build with the error:

> /home/travis/.../vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/diff-lcs-1.2.5/spec/diff_spec.rb:6:in `block in ': uninitialized constant Diff::LCS::SpecHelper (NameError)

My app isn't using diff-lcs directly; it seems to be something internally required by rspec.

[Full build log here](https://travis-ci.org/lynnfaraday/aresmush/jobs/39005701)

[Full Source code here](https://github.com/lynnfaraday/aresmush).

Things I have tried so far:

- Check dependencies - travis' bundler is using the same version as my local box for all dependencies
- Add "require 'diff-lcs'" to Rakefile and my internal spec-helper - didn't help
- Google - couldn't find anything similar

**Travis Config:**

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.1.0
cache: bundler
```

**Gemfile.lock:**

```
rspec (2.14.1)
  rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
rspec-core (2.14.8)
rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
```

**.rspec**

```
-c 
--default_path . 
--pattern **/*_spec*.rb
--require spec_helper
```

Comment: the gem should not be loading files from the spec folder like `diff-lcs-1.2.5/spec/diff_spec.rb:6` what's going on there?

Comment: @phoet - I added my .rspec file - do you think my path or pattern is messing it up?

Comment: Definitely the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying the pattern as `**/*_spec*.rb`, you're telling RSpec to search for spec files in *all* directories inside your project.

You also have Bundler configured to install gems into your project directory, so RSpec is searching through all of your gems and trying to run *their* specs as well as your own.

A better pattern to use would be something such as `spec/**/*_spec.rb` (assuming that all of your specs are within a `spec` directory). This constrains RSpec's search to this path.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess my bundler local configuration is different than Travis' default since I don't see that problem locally.   Is there a way to specify two directories for the pattern?  I have specs in spec/** and also plugins/foo/spec/**, which is why I used that pattern originally.  I can make the rake task test both separately if need be; just wondering if there's a way to combine them.

Comment: Yes, [you can have multiple patterns separated by commas](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/pattern-option#the-`--pattern`-flag-can-be-used-to-pass-in-multiple-patterns,-separated-by-commas)

Comment: Thanks - I missed that in the documentation.  That fixed it!